# I have problem regarding jquery contains syntax error

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery :contains() Selector with which I am finding my question and remove the class from that but in that, I have face syntax error issue I have show my code below.

```js
var question = 'A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8';

$('.wrap .view_all_que:contains('+question+')').parent('li').removeClass('current-question');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="current-question">
            <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="question-dot"></span>
            <a class="view_all_que">
                <p>A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8</p>
            </a>
        </li>
                                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

and it shows me:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .wrap
>   .view_all_que:contains(A penetration tester is conducting a port scan
>   on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were
>   confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed.
>   Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be
>   installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at
>   2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s
>   latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open
>   ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn
>   515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address:
>   00:00:48:0D:EE:8)

Can anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the search expression in quotes, eg

```
$('.wrap .view_all_que:contains("' + question + '")').parent('li').removeClass('current-question');
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add `quotes` around variable question. try like this.

```
$('.wrap .view_all_que:contains("'+question+'")')
```

```js
var question = 'A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8';

$('.wrap .view_all_que:contains("'+question+'")').parent('li').removeClass('current-question');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="current-question">
            <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="question-dot"></span>
            <a class="view_all_que">
                <p>A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8</p>
            </a>
        </li>
                                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the double quotes! Add them and it will work as you wish

```js
var question = 'A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8';

$('.wrap .view_all_que:contains("'+question+'")').parent('li').removeClass('current-question');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="current-question">
            <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="question-dot"></span>
            <a class="view_all_que">
                <p>A penetration tester is conducting a port scan on a specific host. The tester found several ports opened that were confusing in concluding the Operating System (OS) version installed. Considering the NMAP result below, which of the follow is likely to be installed on the target machine by the OS? Starting NMAP 5.21 at 2011-03-15 11:06 NMAP scan report for 172.16.40.65 Host is up (1.00s latency). Not shown: 993 closed ports PORT STATE SERVICE 21/tcp open ftp 23/tcp open telnet 80 /tcp open http 139/tcp open netbios-ssn 515/tcp open 631/tec open ipp 9100/tcp open MAC Address: 00:00:48:0D:EE:8</p>
            </a>
        </li>
                                        
    </ul>
</div>
```